# Valid FFmpeg parameters for Facebook Messenger video upload

Tags: ffmpeg, facebook, facebook-chat

I'm trying to stitch together a bunch of images to form a video with `FFmpeg` (Latest static release by Zeranoe, 3.2.4).

My current command is:

`-i "%d.png" -mbd rd -c:v libx264  -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2 -g 300 -pass 1 -r 60 -y "Output.mp4"`

Where `"%d.png"` points to all my images.

This command successfully creates a video that can be opened by VLC or Media Player (Classic/Home cinema) yet it fails to open with Movies and TV (Windows 10 app) and it also fails to upload to a Messenger chat.

While reading the Facebook manual, I couldn't find any detail about video encoders and such.

Can you provide me a valid FFmpeg command that creates a valid video (by Facebook standards)?

Comment: Solution is to add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as mentioned in linked answer. Other stuff: remove `-mbd rd -flags +mv4+aic -trellis 2 -cmp 2 -subcmp 2` as these are already set by the encoding preset (default is `-preset medium`). Add `-movflags +faststart`. No need for multiple passes.

Comment: Thanks, but now I have to solve "Width not divisible by 2" before trying this command. Tying `-vf scale=-2:Height`...